# Why is AbstractCollection throwing exception instead of AbstractList when using Arrays.asList().addAll

Tags: java, arrays, exception

I am not asking why the error is reported, but I think it should be called AbstractList.addAll to throw an exception

---

demo1(can't understand):

```
public class TestAbstractList {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<String> tmp = new ArrayList<>(
        );
        tmp.add("kk");

        List<String> list = Arrays.asList("3");
        // list.add("kk");
        list.addAll(tmp);
    }
}
```

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
    at java.util.AbstractList.add(AbstractList.java:148)
    at java.util.AbstractList.add(AbstractList.java:108)
    at java.util.**AbstractCollection**.addAll(AbstractCollection.java:344)
    at com.clinbrain.md.metadata.TestAbstractList.main(TestAbstractList.java:15)
```

According to the object returned by Arrays.asList, its parent class is AbstractList (also addAll). AbstractList inherits AbstractCollection. According to the principle of jvm calling method (invokeinterface or invokevirtual), **it should be AbstractList.addAll that throws an exception**, and the result is indeed AbstractCollection.addAll throws exception

---

demo2(understandable):

```
public class TestAbstractList {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<String> tmp = new ArrayList<>(
        );
        tmp.add("kk");

        List<String> list = Arrays.asList("3");
        list.add("kk");
        // list.addAll(tmp);
    }
}
```

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
    at java.util.AbstractList.add(AbstractList.java:148)
    at java.util.**AbstractList**.add(AbstractList.java:108)
    at com.clinbrain.md.metadata.TestAbstractList.main(TestAbstractList.java:14)
```

Comment: Can you please point us to the source code of that `addAll` method in `AbstractList`?

Comment: See `list.addAll(0, tmp)` versus `list.addAll(tmp)`

Answer (score 2):

`AbstractList` does not override the [`addAll(Collection<? extends E>)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/AbstractCollection.html#addAll(java.util.Collection)). It merely inherits the method from `AbstractCollection`. If you go to the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/AbstractList.html) of `AbstractList`, you can see that `addAll` is listed as one of the "Methods declared in class `java.util.AbstractCollection`".

<sub>Note that there is also an `addAll(int, Collection<? extends E>)` that *is* declared in `AbstractList`, but that is a different method.</sub>

The type returned by `Arrays.asList` - `Arrays.ArrayList` doesn't override `addAll(Collection<? extends E>)` either, which is why you see `AbstractCollection` in the stack trace when you call `addAll`.

On the other hand, `AbstractList` does override `add` (but `Arrays.ArrayList` doesn't), so you see `AbstractList` when you call `add`.

Comment: you are right!!!   I read it wrong, in fact addAll(Collection) is in the subList class, this class is also in the AbstractList file, I was too careless, sorry